# How can I handle several files in the same program using a single header?

Tags: c, header-files

I struggle to understand the way the C manual recommends to write functions in separate files.

When I want to write functions in a separate file with respect to the main, what I usually do is create a header file `stuff.h` and put everything there:

```
// this is the stuff.h file 

int function_from_stuff(int b)
{
    return 2*b;
}
```

then in the file `main.c` I will write

```
// this is the main.c file 

#include "stuff.h"

int main()
{
    int b=2;
    int a=function_from_stuff(b);
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

and it all works well.

In the manual (chapter 4.5 Header Files in my edition) , they rather recommend to have several `.c` files where the functions are defined, and to use the header file only to declare them. So, in my trivial example, they would do something like

```
// this is the stuff.h file 

int function_from_stuff(int b);
```

and then also create a another separate `second_file.c` file:

```
// this is the second_file.c file 

#include "stuff.h"

int function_from_stuff(int b)
{
    return 2*b;
}
```

Now, what I do not understand is how this can work, what the compiling order must be, and how I am going to signal the machine that I want `second_file.c` to be part of the program.

Comment: First of all: no, yo don't put code in a header files even if it kind of works on your simplistic example. What they suggest in chapter 4.5 in your C text book is correct.

Comment: depending on the way you compile, you will have to tell it to include the header file as well as compiling all the .c files required to build your main.c

Comment: Both files `main.c` and `second_file.c` are compiled separately into object files, the order of compilation doesn't matter. Then the two object files are linked together with the linker which will produce a executable. I'm sure this is covered in your C text book.

Comment: The whole compilation/linking process depends on your platform/OS/compiler/IDE.

Comment: Building a C program is done in multiple steps: 1) Edit source file(s); 2) Build source file(s) into object file(s); 3) Link object file(s) with libraries into the executable program. When starting out with just a single source file it's common to use a single command to do both the second and third steps behind the scenes. For larger projects you can't really do that, but need to build each separate source file and then explicitly link them.

Comment: This might also be a good time to learn about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (commonly abbreviated as TU).

Comment: "_way the C manual recommends to write functions in separate files._"... The intention is probably "functionality in separate files." Your project may have several UI functions that are conceptually separate from "the mill" of processing data separate from communications with a network. Each of the function _categories_ suggests a chance to locate supporting code in its own source file. Simple "organisation" for larger projects. One or more "header" files informs the source code files of their common interests.

Answer (score -1):

How exactly to do this is entirely dependent on which compiler you use.

> what the compiling order must be

The order in which source files are compiled is not particularly important. Each produces an object file, which are then linked together. I suggest you read up on the compilation process if you want to know more about this.

> how I am going to signal the machine that I want second_file.c to be part of the program.

This is generally done by simply adding adding `second_file.c` to your list of source files, but again this is compiler-dependent.